# Using a specific npm config having more than one registry

Tags: javascript, npm, registry, package.json

I have the following scenario. Currently, I have a react project using two registries the public npm registry and a private registry for my company packages.

I want to apply a configuration only for my private registry to use this config: save-prefix="". Basically  I want to enforce developers to use exact versions rather without using the ^ or ~ strategies.

Is this possible, I was able to create a .npmrc at the project level, and it is working, but for all packages, is there a way to do it only for a specific registry?

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-your-registry-settings-as-an-npm-enterprise-user. I had the same issue and I figured out  the way they said there. However, you might face some issue with proxy if your company is using it.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I actually went through that doc to configure my company registry. And that's working, the thing is I need to set a config property for that specific registry (the private one) without affecting the other packages.